# Get Length of Control.Tag

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find the length of a control's tag to determine a Boolean's value. I've tried a couple methods to get the text length of a Tag in a control and determine if it has a length of 1 or higher, but none of them seem to be working. They all end up with a `System.NullReferenceException` error.

```
Boolean = Control.Tag.ToString.Length > 1
Boolean = Control.Tag.ToString.Count > 1
Boolean = Not Control.Tag.Equals("")
Boolean = Not Control.Tag.ToString.Equals("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because your `Tag` is `Null` (or as it's called in VB `Nothing`).
So before you check the length of the Tag, you need to make sure it's not `Nothing`. e.g with:

```vb
If Control.Tag Is Nothing Then ...
```

Comment: Ah ok I understand now, didn't think about that. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If this solved your problem please click the *Accept this answer* checkmark left of my answer to mark this question as answered.

Comment: Yes I will, I have to wait 5 minutes though, so I will once the timer is up!

Answer (score 1):

Before accessing a method or property of the tag, you must make sure that the tag is not `Nothing`. You can do this in a single expression by using shortcut evaluation:

```
Dim isDefined As Boolean = Control.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso Control.Tag.ToString.Length > 1
```

Since VB 14.0 / Visual Studio 2015 you can use a Null-conditional operator

```
Dim isDefined As Boolean = If(Control.Tag?.ToString.Length, 0) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET you can use VB.NET specific way as the VB Runtime evaluates `Nothing` as an empty string which is represented by `String.Empty`.

In VB.NET you can assign `Nothing` to any variable regardless it is a value type or a reference type.

Its C# equivalent is `default(T)` which for reference types returns `null` and for value types returns the value represented by a state where all bits are zero. E.g. `default(bool)` returns `false`

So these ways are also working:

```
' Let's assume you set the Control.Tag property value to this variable
Dim controlTag As Object = Nothing

' Len() method can accept any Object
Dim controlTagLength As Integer = Len(controlTag)
Dim hasValueByLength As Boolean = controlTagLength > 0

' Always call Equals() method on a constant 
' or on a well defined non-null value e.g. String.Empty
' to avoid NullReferenceException
Dim hasValueByInstanceEquals As Boolean = String.Empty.Equals(controlTag)

' Or you can use the static Equals() method that accepts Object
Dim hasValueByStaticEquals As Boolean = String.Equals(controlTag, String.Empty)
```